# How to sort CSV rows by a single column using PANDAS python

Tags: python, pandas, csv, sorting

Currently on my project I am trying to sort the rows of a CVS sheet by a singular column, I am using PANDAS and I have seen several examples posted all around the internet, however when trying to implement this myself I have been unable to.

```py
db = pd.read_csv(databasefile, skip_blank_lines=True, names=['ExampleOne','ExampleTwo','ExampleThree','ExampleFour'], header=1)
db.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)

db.sort_values(by=['ExampleOne'], ascending=[True])

db.to_csv(databasefile, index=False)
```

In the code above my thought would be that I am turning a CSV into a dataframe for PANDAS to use, in that dataframe I am dropping any duplicated rows and am sorting by the ExampleOne Column. In the end I am sending that information back to the CSV. However, when viewing the CSV after the code runs with no errors the data is not sorted in any order.

[Database CSV Link](https://anotepad.com/notes/s8xaa77)

Here is the CSV in a txt format, the first 60 or so rows are sorted but that is becuase earlier in this process I am combining multiple CSV's together into one CSV.

Thankyou for reading! I would appreciate any help or suggestions anyone would have me try out as this problem has been frustrating for me. Thanks again for reading!

Comment: `db.sort_values(by=['ExampleOne'], ascending=[True], inplace=True)` or you can chain the operations: `db.sort_values(by=['ExampleOne'], ascending=[True]).to_csv(databasefile, index=False)`.

Comment: @QuangHoang I have yet to try that out as I am updating some software on my computer, would chaining the .to_csv function to the sort function actually make a difference? Thankyou for the reply, ill be sure to check it out when my computer is back online

Comment: Yes, sort_values without inplace returns the sorted dataframe, not sort your original.

Comment: @QuangHoang Thankyou very much! works flawlessly now, I didnt realize that sorting did not replace the original dataframe. Once again thankyou!

Answer (score 1):

```
databasefile = r"path"
databasefile2 = r"path"
db = pd.read_csv(databasefile, skip_blank_lines=True, names=['ExampleOne','ExampleTwo','ExampleThree','ExampleFour'], header=1)
print(db['ExampleOne'])
db.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
db.sort_values(by=['ExampleOne'], ascending=True).to_csv(databasefile, index=False)
```

Here is a solution to your problem.